# meaning of "yet" "as if"

Tags: meaning, adverbs, conjunctions

I don't understand the second part of this sentence:

> The Berlin Congress of 1878 and the first set of frontiers drawn on
>   maps ignored key components of local life, *and **yet** they were drawn **as
>   if** they represented territorial definitions on the map in human terms*

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure "to represent territorial definitions on the map in human terms" has any real meaning.

Answer (score 3):

**as if** means that happens while giving a (false) impression.

> He acted *as if* he owned the place.

He acted in such a fashion that the impression was created that he was the proprietor of the place.

**and yet** means that something happens, even if the context makes it unexpected:

> I am old, *and yet* I learn new things.

Old people often do not learn much anymore. I am old, *but* I *still* learn.

The two together:

> He knew nothing about cooking, *and yet* he acted *as if* he were a starred chef.

People who know nothing about cooking probably will not act in a way that professional chefs do. *However*, he *did* exactly that. He was not really a starred chef, of course, but he tried to give us that impression.

Comment: Good analysis and re-synthesis.

Answer (score 0):

the "yet" and "as if" here expresses disappointment that the maps were drawn presuming they covered an aspect which they actually didn't and that there may be an anomaly.

Comment: It may express surprise, but in this context I doubt there is much disappointment. I don't think anyone would have assumed the 1878 maps to be effectively useful today, only to find they were wrong. I think a statement is made about the maps being more or less intentionally inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Meaning:-
As if is used to say how something seems from the information known. Also, it can be used as **Like**.
 **yet** expresses determination of activity in  time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with

> and yet they were drawn as if they represented territorial definitions on the map in human terms

is that the borders do represent territorial definitions (tautologically), but the "human terms" ought to be elsewhere.  Maybe the author should have said:

> and yet they were drawn as if the boundaries represented human social realities.